# Access Pop Up Form Background Garbled/Distorted When Opened via OpenForm Macro Action with Window Mode Normal

Tags: forms, ms-access, macros, modal-dialog, ms-access-2013

I have a database that I work on using Access 2013, though I must maintain compatibility with Access 2010; I am using Windows 7.

I have an input form that is set to Pop Up = Yes, and Modal = No.  When opening this input form directly from the Navigation Pane, it functions perfectly normally.

I have a macro in a search form that calls up this input form with the specified record using the "OpenForm" action.  When opening the input form with this macro, the form's background is totally garbled (it pulls the background image from whatever was behind it when called, as though it were transparent), and all labels are unreadable.

That said, if I run the macro again by trying to open a different record, the form then appears correctly until it is closed.  Also, if I change the "Window Mode" in the "OpenForm" action to "Dialog" rather than "Normal," it appears correctly.

Neither of these are valid solutions, though -- it should work on the first time, and I do not want the form to be modal.  All my code seems okay (insomuch as I am not receiving error messages), so I don't understand why it would be doing this... any guidance is very much appreciated.

Comment: Just an update to make it known that this is still occurring, unfortunately...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have discovered what is causing this problem, though I don't understand why.

The macro I am using came from a sample database, and has some commands I am not fully familiar with.  One such command is "Requery."

I experimented with removing various parts of the macro with the window mode as "Normal" for the "OpenForm" command.  As soon as I tried removing "Requery" (and nothing else) the window opened in "Normal" mode with no distortion whatsoever.

**In short, having "Requery" in the macro was what was causing this error to occur.**  It seems like an innocuous enough action (all it does is refresh data, from what I understand, as described here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb177360(v=office.12).aspx), but since I don't see why its inclusion was necessary anyway (if anyone could shed some light on that, it would be appreciated), it looks like this is essentially solved.

I hope this may help someone else in the future!